# Core Data - Saving & Retrieving Attributes - Sample Code

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've gone through quite a few Core Data tutorials. Most of them show how to add a new object to an entity and how to display the updated array of fetched objects.

My goal, however, is much simpler: I'd like one Table View Controller to change and save an attribute (in tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) of an entity and another Table View Controller to display the new list of attributes of that entity (in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:). Like in the iPhone *Sounds* settings: 
[Sounds](http://holyteddy.com/sounds.jpg) and
[Ringtones](http://holyteddy.com/ringtone.jpg)

I still haven't figured out how the Managed Object should interact with those two Table View Controllers.
Do you know of a helpful tutorial/sample code explaining that very simple process?
Thanks very much in advance!
Saeppi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this tutorial.[core data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started).

Comment: Thanks very much! Running the App on the iPhone works fine, but only if it stays connected to the Mac/linked to Xcode. If I try to run it after I disconnected it, Core Data does not work anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure.  If you were referring the tutorial on that site.  I would post a question on that site.